# How to find coordinates of dot ( x, y, z) if you have only function which returns distance between SECRET and any inputed dot, using JS?

Tags: javascript, math, logic, binary-search-tree, do-while

I have a test task. It sounds like this.
Write 2 functions. **The first** function must contain a secret point, let's say [ 12, 45, 99 ]. This point is in 3D space and its coordinates can only take integer values ​​from 0 to 100.
This function takes an arbitrary point as an argument and calculates the distance from the secret point to the given one.

```
const secretPoint = [12, 45, 99];

export default function getDistance(manualPoint) {
  if (manualPoint.length !== 3) {
    console.error("Wrong manualPoint!");
  }
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < manualPoint.length; i++) {
    const difference = secretPoint[i] - manualPoint[i];

    sum += Math.pow(difference, 2);
  }
  const result = Math.sqrt(sum);
  return result;
}
```

The **second function** must find the coordinates of the SECRET point in the least number of calls to the first function.

And here's the problem, because I don't know how to do it right. It is logical to assume that the fastest search on a sorted array of data is a binary search. In our case, this is suitable, because. we are looking for 3 coordinates ranging from 0 to 100.

In order not to complicate my task, I decided to first write a function that would search for a coordinate in only 1 plane.

Here is how I tried to do it. I have a minimum value - 0 and a maximum value - 100.
So we call the first function with the given values `[0 0 0] / [0 0 100]`
And we compare the result. If in the first case the distance to the secret point is greater than in the second case. So the desired coordinate 0 0 Z lies in the range from 50 to 100. And we continue in the same way to reduce the search area for the point.

This function is incorrect, I know. But somehow sometimes it gives me correct values, but sometimes  there is an error by 1 or 2.

```
const secretPoint = [12, 45, 99];



function binarySearch() {
  let left = 0;
  let right = 100;
  let mid;

  while (left <= right) {

    mid = (right - left) / 2 + left;

    if (getDistance([0, 0, left]) < getDistance([0, 0, right])) {

      console.log(Math.floor(mid));

      right = mid - 1;

    } else {

      console.log(Math.floor(mid));
      left = mid + 1;

    }
  }
  return -1;
}

binarySearch();
```

Output is like this:
50
75
88
94
97
99

So now it works fine somehow, but let's change secretPoint to

```
const searchPoint = [12, 45, 28];
```

and Output is like this:
50
24
37
30
27
29

So it's wrong.

Comment: How can you not know the location if your distance calculation uses the location?

Comment: This is part of the assignment. I have indicated the data of the secret point just for clarity. In fact, there will be random values.

Comment: "So the desired coordinate 0 0 Z lies in the range from 50 to 100": unless you use the L∞ distance, this conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points at a given distance from a center lie on a sphere with that radius. Two centers define two spheres, which intersect on a circle.  A third sphere determines two points on the circle. And finally, a fourth point is necessary to discriminate between these two.

So you essentially need to implement an algorithm for the intersections of three spheres.

---

The equation of a sphere is quadratic in X, Y, Z with a special form. By subtracting two pairs of equations, you obtain two linear equations which are those of two planes. The intersection of these planes is a straight line. By writing the parametric equation of the line, it is easy to obtain the intersection points with one of the spheres.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not a mathematician. And to implement an algorithm without knowing the formula seems to me an extremely difficult task. Perhaps you are right, most likely you are right, because my function only works partially. I was just trying to implement a simple binary search to get the result and failed.

Comment: @tresor13: my answer explains that you cannot do with less than 4 attempts. Your dichotomic search must be generalized to 3D and account for possible non-montonicities. For what course is that ?

Comment: It’s a test task for company. But I’ve already found the problem of my formula so the function finds right coordinate for 7 iterations.

Comment: @tresor13: 4 is always enough. In some cases, less.

Comment: Could you please provide a formula?

Comment: @tresor13: lookup the formula for a sphere and work out the equations.